# blank screen after suspend: nouveau says link training failed

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card

When I resume my HP 8440p from standby, my display gets activated but remains blank - just a white screen.

The journal shows the following log entries when going down for standby:

```
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
```

and when resuming, nouveau tells me that `link training failed`:

```
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming display...
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: outp 00:0006:0344: link training failed
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: outp 00:0006:0344: link training failed
Mar 24 22:15:00 myNotebook kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: outp 00:0006:0344: link not trained before attach
```

I don't want to use the official nvidia driver because it brings other issues. Some details about my system:

```
lspci | grep NV
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

uname -r
4.4.5-1-ARCH

pacman -Ss nouveau | grep installed
extra/mesa 11.1.2-1 [installed]
extra/xf86-video-nouveau 1.0.12-1 (xorg-drivers xorg) [installed]
multilib/lib32-mesa 11.1.2-1 [installed]
```

Comment: superuser.com isn't really for issue like this. you should just report a bug report upstream: https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/Bugs/ especially when you're using Arch (hence a very recent upstream kernel). 4.5 is already out btw, you can also test it first before reporting, if you can manage that.

Comment: @Ethan: have you found any solution? I am facing the same issue, and have searched around without any success up until now

Comment: No. The only "solution" is to never buy Nvidia again. With Intel HD graphics you never have such issues.